# Date '2017/02/23' not recognized in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a csv with example data as:

> 61| MXN| Mexican Peso| 2017/02/23

I'm trying to insert this into snowflake using the following commands:

```
create or replace stage table_stage file_format = (TYPE=CSV,ENCODING = 'WINDOWS1252');

copy into table from @table_stage/table.csv.gz file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|' error_on_column_count_mismatch=false, ENCODING = 'WINDOWS1252');

put file://table.csv @table_stage auto_compress=true
```

But I get the error as

> Date '2017/02/23' not recognized

Using `alter session set date_input_format = 'YYYY-DD-MM'` to change the date format fixes it.

But what can I add in the create stage or the copy command itself to change the date format?

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake has session parameter [`DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#date-input-format) that control over the input format for DATE data type.

The default value is `AUTO` specifies that Snowflake attempts to automatically detect the format of dates stored in the system during the session meaning the `COPY INTO <table>` command attempts to match all date strings in the staged data files with one of the formats listed in [Supported Formats for AUTO Detection](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#supported-formats-for-auto-detection).

To guarantee correct loading of data, Snowflake strongly recommends explicitly setting the file format options for data loading (as explain in [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#data-loading))

To solve your issue you need to set the `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT` parameter with the expected format of dates in your staged files.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the date format in the file format: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DATE_FORMAT` parameter in file_format condition.
More you can read here: [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html)

```sql
copy into table 
from @table_stage/table.csv.gz 
file_format = (TYPE=CSV
               FIELD_DELIMITER='|'
               ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE
               ENCODING = 'WINDOWS1252'
               DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```